# the Type or namespace name ‘ImageProcessing’ does not exist in the namespace ‘System’(are you missing an assembly reference)?

Tags: c#

The following is the code for Median Filter . I am getting

> Error as ---- the Type or namespace name ‘ImageProcessing’ does not exist in the namespace ‘System’(are you missing an assembly reference)?

```
private void medianToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
    pictureBox1.Image = img;
    img = System.ImageProcessing.BitmapImage.MedianFilter(img);
    pictureBox1.Image = (Image)img;
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Done");
}
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Have you referenced System.Drawing assembly?

Comment: Thanks for replying..Yes I have used sir

Comment: I have used as System.Drawing

Comment: Where did you find `System.ImageProcessing.BitmapImage.MedianFilter`method? Can you show us some documentation?

Comment: I can only conclude that you're trying to call a `MedianFilter` method that also exists inside your own code base, and you've somehow got the namespacing wrong.